# Print arranged from User input

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, printing

I have a form with several TextBox lines of user input and an image.

I want to be able to have data printed in a certain arrangement.

User just presses Button to print.

Here's [a link](http://i1204.photobucket.com/albums/bb414/ruffusmagnium/printSetupExample_zps6cfb5db3.jpg) to a example of what I want printout to look like.

Comment: Take a look at the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) and [PrintPreviewDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.aspx) classes.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you have and how you want it to be printed?

Comment: Add a PrintDocument Control and Add the textbox to the PrintDocument and then set the PrintPreviewDialog Document property to the print document

Comment: the PrintForm control will work nicely for that.  Just have the controls arranged the way you want.

Comment: @ Neolisk here is [link](http://i1204.photobucket.com/albums/bb414/ruffusmagnium/printSetupExample_zps6cfb5db3.jpg) to sample. currently working on suggestions posted here. Still not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy sample ..

```
Dim pd as New PrintDocument

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

     pd.Print()

End Sub

Private Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage

    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox.Text, TextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 100)

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, 200, 200) '----> imagein picture box

End Sub
```

ADDED :

To centering text

```
Dim x as Single = Convert.ToSingle(e.PageBounds.Width / 2 - e.Graphics.MeasureString(TextBox.Text, TextBox1.Font).Width / 2)

e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox.Text, TextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, x, 100)
```

Comment: thnx matzone, but I am still looking for a way to arrange text, such as center and align.

Comment: getting error: Error 1 Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types. for ...Handles pd.PrintPage.... in pd_PrintPage, I'm working to resolve this though

Comment: thnx got working with change 'pd' declaration to WithEvents now just have to tool around with spacing

Comment: helpful [link](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_print_scaled_and_centered.html) to centering images